# Exibir valor de array no php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou colocando valores em um `array` e preciso exibir esses valores do lado dos titulos nos `th` de uma `table`.

Não quero usar um loop para percorrer o array, quero acessar o valor pelo indice.

Segue minha função que alimenta o `array` e envia para a `view`

```
public function index() {

    $novas = $this->model->countSituacaoNova();
    $analise = $this->model->countSituacaoAnalise();
    $aprovada = $this->model->countSituacaoAprovada();
    $reprovada = $this->model->countSituacaoReprovada();
    $pendente = $this->model->countSituacaoPendente();
    $paga = $this->model->countSituacaoPaga();

    $data = array(
        'novas' => $novas,
        'analise' => $analise,
        'aprovada' => $aprovada,
        'reprovada' => $reprovada,
        'pendente' => $pendente,
        'paga' => $paga
        );

    $situacoes['situacao'] = $data;

    //var_dump($data);
    $this->load->view('propostas_view', $situacoes);
}
```

Segue um trecho da `view` com a `table` na qual tento usar o valor do `array`

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Em análise (<?php echo $situacao['novas']; ?>)</th>
        <th>Aprovadas</th>
        <th>Reprovadas</th>
        <th>Pendentes</th>
        <th>Pagas</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

meu `array` `$novas` tem isso:

```
  array (size=1)
 0 => 
   object(stdClass)[22]
     public 'Novas' => string '1' (length=1)
```

> Erro: `Message: Array to string conversion`

Comment: Qual erro que da ?

Comment: `Message: Array to string conversion`

Comment: Da um dd() no seu array e ve o conteudo dele

Comment: A variável `$novas` está recebendo um valor inteiro mesmo? Cheque se não está vindo um array.

Comment: verdade.. está vindo um array em `$novas`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com a sua descrição para o array $novas, o valor pode ser obtido da seguinte forma, pois há o Objeto "Novas" dentro da posição 0 desse vetor:

`$novas[0]->Novas`

Comment: `Undefined index: Novas`

Comment: qual das 3 tentativas você utilizou?

Comment: a primeira tentativa.. na segunda o mesmo problema

Comment: experimente trocar por $query->result()[0]['Novas']; e $query->result()[0]->Novas;

Comment: não deu certo... editei a pergunta

Comment: editei minha resposta aqui também

Answer (score 0):

Você tá recebendo um `array` no índice "novas". Por isso que tá sendo disparado o erro.

**Se sua model retorna um array**:

Troque esse trecho:

`<?php echo $situacao['novas']; ?>`

Por esse:

`<?php echo $situacao['novas']['Novas']; ?>`

**Se sua model retorna um objeto**:

Troque esse trecho:

`<?php echo $situacao['novas']; ?>`

Por esse:

`<?php echo $situacao['novas']->Novas; ?>`

Comment: editei a pergunta e coloquei o array `$novas`... tentei mas deu o seguinte erro: `Undefined index: Novas`

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu model retorna apenas um registro deveria usar `result_row()` no lugar de `result()` que devolve mais de um e necessita de for/foreach.

Para acessar o valor corretamente na sua view faça:

```
foreach($situacao['novas'] as $item){
   echo $item->Nova .'<br>';
}
```

Ou para um registro com `result_row()`

```
echo $stituacao['novas']->Novas;
```